# Join entity properties in form

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to join two properties in an entity collection form field ?

So that the select input displays soemthing like this:

property1 - Property 2

So far, my builder field looks like this

```
->add('arrival', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'AOFVHFlyBundle:Airport',
'property' => 'name',
'query_builder' => function($repository) {
                                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                    ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                            },
))
```

But obviously, it only returns the name property. My Airport Entity has a "name" property and a "Code" property, I would like to display something like 
[Airpot Name] - [Airport Code]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Tell form to use a property that doesn't exists in entity:

```
->add('arrival', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'AOFVHFlyBundle:Airport',
'property' => 'virtualProperty', // <- set to value that doesn't actually exists
'query_builder' => function($repository) {
                                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                    ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                            },
))
```

And in your entity create a getter for this "property" like:

```
public function getVirtualProperty()
{
    return $this->getName() . ' - ' . $this->getCode();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return a querybuilder that select `CONCAT(u.name, ' - ', u.code) AS virtualProperty` ?

Comment: That won't work since results are mapped to entities first. You entity won't contain this property, so it won't be mapped. Anyway you don't need that, because you can simply do that as shown in the answer.